# Shell in Pure Eclipse E4

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

How to get a shell from workbench window in Eclipse e4 or else do we have to use the same which we following in eclipse 3.x?

Could anyone please help me? My aim is to develop a pure e4 project.

Comment: Can you elaborate please, I don't understand what you are asking. There is no 'workbench window' in a pure e4 application, do you mean the main window? What do you want to use the shell for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to open a dialog or something like that from a handler you normally use the active shell. This is stored in the Eclipse context under the name `IServiceConstants.ACTIVE_SHELL`.

You can get this in a handler by injecting it - something like:

```java
@Execute
public void execute(@Named(IServiceConstants.ACTIVE_SHELL) Shell shell)
{
   ..
}
```

If you are not in an injected class you can use the `Display` method:

```java
Shell shell = Display.getDefault().getActiveShell();
```

Comment: Thanks. In 3.x we take active shell form workbench like following PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow(),getShell(). what is similar to this in the Eclipse E4. Sorry, I am new to Eclipse e4.

Comment: There is no call like that. In e4 most of the time you will be in a handler when you want the active shell. If you have some other requirement please explain it in more details.

Comment: I want an active shell inside an Action class, which will open a file dialog on click. To open the file dialog I want the shell.

Comment: If you have no access to an injected class you can always use the SWT `Display.getDefault().getActiveShell()` method (added to answer).